# Append line with sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, sed, append

In a bash script I have to append a line into a systemd file. The file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
...
```

The line must be appended under the [Unit] section and after all the lines in this section:

```
[Unit]
...
---MY LINE--- 

[Service]
...
```

I know how to append the line directly after [Unit]:

```
[Unit]
---MY LINE---
...

[Service]
...
```

with sed like this:

```
$ sed '/\[Unit\]/a ---MY LINE---' input_file
```

but how can I append my line after all the lines in the section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU `awk` in your system, you can use the following script. It appends the string right before the start of the next section.

```
awk -v RS='\\[[^]]*\\]' '{printf $0; if(oRT~/Unit/){print "---MY LINE---"}; printf RT; oRT=RT}' input_file
```

`RS` is the record separator. It is a regex set to anything between square bracket, such that it matches both `[Unit]` and `[Service]`. Having such a `RS` allows to have a record with the full content of a block section.

`RT` is the record terminator. It is set dynamically by `awk` for each record based on `RS`.  It will hold successively `[Unit]` and `[Service]`.

The trick is to store the record terminator in the variable `oRT`. If this one has the word `Unit` then append the wanted string `---MY LINE---`.

---

If you want to append the string before the empty line at the end of the section use the following script:

```
awk -v RS='\\[[^]]*\\]' 'oRT~/Unit/{sub(/\n$/,"---MY LINE---\n\n")}{printf $0 RT; oRT=RT}' input_file
```

The `sub` function replaces the empty line at the end of the record by appending the wanted string and an empty line.

Comment: thanks this is good but it puts an empty line between the last line and my line of the [Unit] section and it's right before [Service] without an empty line in between. How can I fix this?

Comment: @coverflower please see the updated answer